# Python: PermissionError while writing a file to windows dir

Tags: python, permissions

When i want to open a file in C:\ (windows dir.) this error shows up:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\h.txt'

What should i do?

I know this question has been asked several times but i can't find solution!

code:

```
f=open ('C:\\h.txt','w')
f.write ('python')
f.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not on win machine, but give this a try, you can manage permissions using these [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories)
Try to open your file using `os.fdopen`

```
 import os
 with os.fdopen(os.open('file.txt', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0600), 'w') as f:
   f.write(...)
```

**UPDATE**

```
import os
is_accessible = os.access("C:\\temp\\python",os.F_OK) #Check if you have access, this should be a path
if is_accessible == False: #If you don't, create the path
     os.makedirs("C:\\temp\\python")
os.chdir("C:\\temp\\python") # Check now if the path exist 
f = os.open( "p.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT ) #Create the file 
os.write(f, b"This is a test \n")  #Try to write 
os.close(f)
```

Comment: @hamedb71 : Try to force creating the path. Check the UPDATE

Comment: Thanks it worked. but it is a little complicated to me so i should study about that. :@

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a Windows machine but perhaps you should try and create this file in the directory c:\Temp.

Likewise make sure you've not got Notepad etc with that file open.

Comment: My problem is that i haven't administrator privilege!

Comment: Perhaps you can use C:\Temp as your working area or just your Desktop `f = open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/h.txt', 'w'))..`